# What is the cause of cracking and corrosion in Trent 1000 engines?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-maintenance, engine-design

According to [this description](http://www.mro-network.com/engines-engine-systems/problems-persist-trent-1000-updates) and [this one](https://www.google.com.sg/amp/s/amp.ft.com/content/7a5ac666-6d47-11e8-852d-d8b934ff5ffa) of some Trent 1000 engine problems, there appears to be a problem with cracking/corrosion of the fan blades, but does anyone have any insight as to why this is the case? (And why this problem doesn't occur on other platforms?)

I was thinking it could be due to the composites used in the compressor fan blades, or perhaps something to do with the no bleed-air system unique to the Trent 1000, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes this much engine damage?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50551/what-causes-this-much-engine-damage)

Comment: Your formulation assumes this engine have more problems than other types. Although this might be true, it looks like astroturfing, and calls for opinion based answers. You should rephrase your question. Sonething like "what cause corrosion damages on jet engines?" Illustrated by this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is sulfidation corrosion, according to this article:
https://airinsight.com/rolls-royce-trent-1000-corrosion-issues/

Turbine blades are made of metal, and they suffer temperatures and forces so high that they are usually 'grown' from a single metal christal. A single blade can cost as much as a luxury car.

The problems also seem to be related. Corrosion leaves a little pit, which turns in to a crack due to the cyclic loads.